# Arrays and pointer in C programming question

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers

I just started doing C recently and I've been stuck at this problem.

There are some integers in an array of even size. Write a C program to rearrange the array such that left-half is in increasing order and right-half is in decreasing order. Print the distances (positive difference) between the corresponding elements from minimum to maximum of the left-half and right-half.

Note: The array must be represented through a pointer. One function sort() must be defined for the necessary rearrangement.

Sample Input:
Enter No. of elements: 6

Enter elements :2 7 4 9 10 3

Output:
2 4 7 10 9 3

1 5 3

```
for (j=0;j<((num/2)-1);j++)
{
    for (i=0;i<((num/2)-1);i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            temp=arr[i]; /* swapping elements (arranging left half in ascending order) */
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
for (j=1;j<(num/2);j++)
{
    for (i=(num/2);i<num;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]<arr[i+1])
        {
            temp=arr[i];   /* arranging right half in descending order */
            arr[i]=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
for (i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
for (i=0;i<(num/2);i++)
{
   if (arr[i]>arr[((num-1)-i)])
   {
       diff=arr[i]-arr[(num-1)-i];
   }
   else
   {
       diff=arr[(num-1)-i]-arr[i];
   }
   printf("%d ",diff);
}
```

}

That is the code I have come up with and it works, but I need to write it with the array being represented with a pointer and I need to enclose it in a function.

Please help me

Comment: Unclear what is meant by "represented as a pointer". If they mean use pointer notation rather than array-subscript notation, replace all instances of `a[i]` with `*(a + (i))`

Comment: Arrays and pointers have a close relationship.  If your code works when `arr` is declared as an array, then it would work exactly the same if `arr` were instead a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: But an array cannot be "represented by" a pointer.  You can have pointers *to* array elements or to whole arrays, but such pointers are not well characterized as "representing" the pointed-to data.

Comment: @Mathew Thomas What does this output 1 5 3 mean?

Comment: ok so the output is basically the positive difference between the left most element and the right most element of the sorted array. So if my input is 6 3 4 1 2 9, the sorted array would be 3 4 6 9 2 1, and the final output would be, (3-1) (4-2) (9-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... I need to write it with the array being represented with a pointer and I need to enclose it in a function.

This is possible. You need to make a few changes to your code:

1. Replace your declaration of `arr[]` with:

   ```
   int *arr;
   ```
2. Then, allocate the required bytes of memory:

   You already ask the user to provide an even number, let's say it `size`. Now, we can allocate the memory like this:

   ```
   arr = (void *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
   ```
3. Either you pass the pointer to an integer or array of an integer, it will be converted into a pointer automatically in the function definition – finding the size of a pointer like an array is not possible. Hence, the sort function's prototype should look like this:

   ```
   void sort(int *arr, const int size)
   ```

This is it. Now, you can manipulate the pointers in the same way you would do with arrays. For example, you can access the values stored in the pointer in two ways. First one is quite simple, just use `arr[0]`, `arr[i]`, etc. On the other hand, you can introduce a dereference operator to obtain the value stored in the pointer:

```
int value_at_1st_index = *(arr + 1);
.
.
int value_at_Nth_index = *(arr + N);
```

Note that `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)`.